# c++ : istream_iterator skip spaces but not newline

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

Suppose I have

```
istringstream input("x = 42\n"s);
```

I'd like to iterate over this stream using `std::istream_iterator<std::string>`

```
int main() {
    std::istringstream input("x = 42\n");
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> iter(input);

    for (; iter != std::istream_iterator<std::string>(); iter++) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I get the following output as expected:

```
x
=
42
```

Is it possible to have the same iteration skipping spaces but not a newline symbol? So I'd like to have

```
x
=
42
\n
```

Comment: Use `\\n` in the input? Effectively, you want to translate the character whose value is `\n` (value is 10 in ascii) to the characters ``\`` and `n`.

Comment: @Justin but that would give 42\n at the final iteration - but I want to have a newline character

Answer (score 2):

`std::istream_iterator` isn't really the right tool for this job, because it doesn't let you specify the delimiter character to use.  Instead, use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), which does.  Then check for the newline manually and strip it off if found:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream input("x = 42\n");
    std::string s;
    while (getline (input, s, ' '))
    {
        bool have_newline = !s.empty () && s.back () == '\n';
        if (have_newline)
            s.pop_back ();
        std::cout << "\"" << s << "\"" << std::endl;
        if (have_newline)
            std::cout << "\"\n\"" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"x"
"="
"42"
"
"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use boost use this:

```
boost::algorithm::split_regex(cont, str, boost::regex("\s"));
```

where "cont" can be the result container and "str" is your input string.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_regex.html